# Why is a random walk's RMS distance from the starting position$\propto\sqrt{N}$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, randomness

Why is the root mean squared (RMS) distance from the starting position of a (1D, 2D, or 3D) random walk of $N$ equally-sized steps proportional to $\sqrt{N}$? Is it also$\propto\sqrt{N}$ for $n$-spatial dimensions, where $n>3$?

Comment: If the $x$, $y$, and $z$ steps are uncorrelated then you have three independent 1D random walks. From there it's easy to figure out.

Comment: @DanielSank I saw a proof that used integrals. I don't recall it being as easy as the proof that focuses on probability (e.g., $\langle\rangle$) rules.

Comment: There are a few ways to look at this. You could just prove the central limit theorem, or you could pick a probability distribution for each step (i.e. 1/2 right and 1/2 left) and solve that case explicitly. Which one do you want?

Comment: @DanielSank That proof would be independent of the number of dimensions?

Comment: It depends on the assumptions. If the left/right steps in each dimension are uncorrelated, then yes, the proof is independent of the number of dimensions.